# Google Sheets no longer loading into Excel Power Query Editor

Tags: excel, google-sheets, powerquery

we have a 3rd party packer who uses Google Sheets to keep a track of production they carry out on our behalf.
For over a year now, i have brought that data into Excel via Power Query Editor and added some sql data off our own server so we can see whether we have processed it in our system or not.
Last Thursday 10th Nov 2022, that process stopped working.

I have tried to rebuild the sheet in Excel, but it still is not working.
Of the 4 sheets I bring into excel, a couple haven't had any data added to them for about a week now.
That suggests to me that the data is not the issue, but the link between Google Sheets and Excel Power Query editor has somehow changed.  Perhaps due to an update in either program.

The error message states:
[DataSource.Error] Web.Contents failed to get contents from
xxxx
xxxx
Bad Request

Does anyone have any ideas what may have caused this?
And, more importantly, know of a fix?

Here's hoping someone can help
regards
Neal

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `Google Sheets built in connector` [image: Google Sheets connector]

Paste the path to your List, authenticate using your google account and it should work.

[image: Loaded]

The link should be in this format (`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXX`

Comment: Many thanks Vojtech, but we have that link that begins like that.  And we also got them to resend so that i could build a new excel - to see if the issue continued.  Unfortunately the issue still occurred. It's very strange that it should stop now after over a year of running okay and some of the google sheets had not been updated since the last successful update in excel.

Comment: Did you also tried using their REST API?
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts
https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/get-started

Comment: Hi Vojtech. Unfortunately i cannot do anything to the google sheets as it belongs to our third party packers.  I just need the link to continue to work as it has done for the last year.  I wonder if some google sheets policies have changed and that is affecting my link to them